# How to skip an item that has already been passed in an arrayList

Tags: android, for-loop, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm iterating over a list in firebase, it works like an arrayList
I use a for loop to iterate over chlidrens as it would be done in a list, I have them randomly iterated with this code

```
    FirebaseUtils.getMeetPeopleListCityReference(ciudadX).orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                            Random random = new Random();
                            final int index = random.nextInt((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                            int count = 0;
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if (count == index) {
                                    final MeetPeopleList mee = snapshot.getValue(MeetPeopleList.class);

                                    if (mee.getIDentificador().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                        // nothing, are you
                                    } else {
                                        testData.add(mee);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But this is the important code
What it does is iterate at random, and here the problem

I need it to iterate over the list, do not repeat the objects that will be listed

I will set an example:
The code works by pressing a button, pressing it shows the entire list of items, a random item on the screen, but clicking again sometimes shows the same as previously shown and I need not show that object That already showed

```
    Random random = new Random();
                            final int index = random.nextInt((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                            int count = 0;
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if (count == index) {
                                    final MeetPeopleList mee = snapshot.getValue(MeetPeopleList.class);

                                    if (mee.getIDentificador().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                        // nothing, are you
                                    } else {
                                        testData.add(mee);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                count++;
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `OnDataChange` store also the keys of the children in a data structure like `Map<String, Boolean>`. On your code you have just to initialize a new Map called `myMap` and add this line inside your for-loop:

```
myMap.put(snapshot.getKey(), true)
```

Then, inside your "random method" just check if value of `myMap` for your key is still `true`. And then set the Boolean value to `false` once you used the element with that key.

Comment: I do not understand very well how to implement it, it would be of great help that you explain me well